# How to find the difference of two numbers and the absolute value of that answer without using math.abs function JAVA

Tags: java

How can I find the absolute value of the difference of two numbers. (BEGINNER)

i.e. My program will compute |a-b| (in that order), WITHOUT using math.abs.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = in.nextDouble();
    double b = in.nextDouble();
    double value = a - b;

    System.out.println("Enter a: ");
    a = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter b: ");
    b = in.nextDouble();

    //If value is negative...make it a positive number.
    value = (value < 0) ? -value : value;

    System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "=" + (a - b));
    System.out.println(b + "-" + a + "=" + (b - a));

}
```

}

PLEASE HELP, I AM A BEGINNER!

Comment: what’s your question? what’s wrong with this

Comment: Why do you yell that you're a beginner?

Comment: @nicomp wow youre right I should definitely stop yelling.

Comment: @Solace, everytime I run the program it doesn't do anything. So I think there is an error in my code somewhere.

Comment: that’s because you have a=in.nextDouble. that line expects user input and you collected user input twice

Comment: Why are you taking input 4 times it should be 2 times

Comment: I see! I deleted the extra two, but my code still doesn't print anything ): @Solace

Comment: type a number and press enter. then do it again

Comment: @indiarain see my answer. It is working now https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2aRk7tDPqu

Comment: @indiarain have your problem solved? If yes then please mark solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit more formatted code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a;
        double b;
        System.out.println("Enter a: ");
        a = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter b: ");
        b = in.nextDouble();
        double value = a - b;



        //If value is negative...make it a positive number.
        value = (value < 0) ? -value : value;
            System.out.println("|"+a + "-" + b +"|" + " =" + value);  // value should be printed here instead of (a-b) or (b-a)
        System.out.println("|"+b + "-" + a +"|" + " =" + value);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are taking scanner two times without any reason

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter a: ");
        double a = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter b: ");
        double b = in.nextDouble();

double value = a - b;
double value2 = b - a;

//If value is negative...make it a positive number.
        value = (value < 0) ? -value : value;
        value2 = (value2 < 0) ? -value2 : value2;

        System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "=" + value); //chaged to value
            System.out.println(b + "-" + a + "=" + value2); //changed to value

        }
```

Comment: why are you taking 2 variable for value. His code is correct for calculating value.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore because `a-b != b-a`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point 'value = a-b' will calculate difference and it will be either positive or negative. Then 'value = (value < 0) ? -value : value;' will eventually make value positive and it will be stored in value variable itself. Check it for yourself if you don't know about ternary operator

Comment: @BrijRajKishore I red it again `difference between two numbers` and now see what you were trying to say. I guess I just made assumption when i saw printing `a-b` and `b-a`. At the end of the day code is still working correct but not optimally

Answer (score 0):

its simple

assume we have two int a and b.
And a variable diff to find the absolute difference.
code:

```
int diff=a-b;
if(diff<0)
diff=b-a;
```

here you will get the absolute value between a and b.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To have an absolute value for your

```
value
```

You can add if condition like below

```
if (value < 0) {
   value = value * -1;
}
```

So that the negative answer (difference) will always be converted to positive (absolute) value.

If the value is greater than 0, then no need as it is already a positive number.